# Are there examples or instructions how to leverage Azure services in Bluemix apps?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Can anyone share some examples and/or instructions how to leverage Azure services in a Bluemix apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Azure service endpoint is publicly accessible over the internet, you can connect to it from your Bluemix application directly. You can create a 'User Defined Service' in Bluemix which will contain the url and credentials of your Azure service (or any other service). You can then bind this user defined service to one or more of your applications, and read the credentials from the VCAP_SERVICES variable.

```
$ cf cups myExternalDB -p "host, username, password"
host> 123.123.123.123
username> myusername
password> mypassw0rd
```

Comment: I have followed this approach. One other thing to consider is that, at least for the Azure SQL Server service, it has a white list of IPs that can connect to it. I don't think Bluemix has published a range of possible IPs, so what I would try next time is using the Bluemix Secure Gateway service, having the Secure Gateway client on an Azure VM, and only allowing the VM to talk to the DB.